# Using Magento 1.7 Grayscale blueskin theme "Not able to change default slider Image"

Tags: jquery, image, slider

I have deleted default images in directory /public_html/media and uploaded my own images with same default name. But I am still viewing default images in my home page slider My custom images are not showing.

In my home page design I am using 2 column left bar with following layout update xml

home_page_header_block                                   skin_csscss/slider.css           skin_jsjs/jquery-1.3.2.min.js           skin_jsjs/cycle-fade-effect.js          skin_jsjs/noconflict.js

Please guide me change default images....